# Submitting a form with casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I have a simple [form](http://m.kamajewellery.com/shop/category/rings/kama-platinum/product/ring-39001) to submit using casperjs. For the same, I have the following version of the code -

```
casper.then(function() {
    // fill the dropdown and click on buy now
    this.fill('form#add-to-cart-form', {
        'options[416]': '2884',
        'productId': '1093'
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    console.log("Checkout URL: ", this.getCurrentUrl()); // not going correctly
});
```

The problem here is that the same [URL](http://m.kamajewellery.com/shop/category/rings/kama-platinum/product/ring-39001) is getting logged by the program, whereas if you open the page and submit it, it goes to the [checkout page](http://m.kamajewellery.com/shop/checkout/cart?context=item_already_in_cart).

Any clue what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site seems to be a single page application. The page load of the submit button isn't picked up by casperjs. You need to manually wait for the next page to load. I used a selector that you can find on the cart page but not on the product page: `.filled-cart`

The other problem was that the fill method didn't trigger the form submit. You need to manually click it. Also I removed the fill for the hidden field, as it doesn't make sense.

```
casper.then(function() {
    // fill the dropdown and click on buy now
    this.fill('form#add-to-cart-form', {
        'options[416]': '2884'
    });
    this.click("button[type=submit]");
});

casper.waitForSelector(".filled-cart");

casper.then(function() {
    console.log("Checkout URL: ", this.getCurrentUrl()); // not going correctly
});
```