# Submitting a form and downloading a file using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Note I've already looked at these links:

[CasperJS and downloading a file via iFrame and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163600/casperjs-and-downloading-a-file-via-iframe-and-javascript)

[Submitting a form with casperjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355770/submitting-a-form-with-casperjs)

I figured they were perfect for what I was trying to accomplish but my efforts have been fruitless.

I am trying to download an mp3 to my filesystem via https://www.youtube2mp3.cc/#conversion and I've been trying to accomplish this headless via CasperJS.

Here is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true , logLevel: "debug" });
var fs = require('fs');
casper.start('http://www.video2mp3.de/');
casper.waitForSelector("#converter > form");
casper.fill('#converter > form', { video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoaUYcwEpSw' }, true);
casper.waitForSelector("#file");
var url = casper.getElementAttribute('#file','href');
var mp3 = fs.absolute("unstoppable.mp3");
casper.then(function() { this.download(url, mp3); });
casper.run();
```

I guess I am being a bit naive in thinking it would be this simple but I can't find my errors. The debugger hasn't been very helpful. I've been running my file with following command in my terminal:

`casperjs --web-security=no sample.js`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**

I managed to get it working by using screen-captures to debug my code. Here is the final result if anyone is interested:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({verbose: true , logLevel: "debug" });
var fs = require('fs');
var url = "https://www.youtube2mp3.cc/"
casper.start(url);
casper.then(function(){
    this.fill('#converter > form', { 'video': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VoaUYcwEpSw' }, true);
});
casper.wait(2000);//this is probably what I was missing, 
                //a screen capture showed that I wasn't waiting long enough
casper.then(function(){
    this.waitForSelector("#file", function(){
        var url = casper.getElementAttribute('#file','href');
        var mp3 = fs.absolute("unstoppable.mp3");
        casper.then(function() { this.download( url, mp3); });
    });
});
casper.run();
```

The downloaded file will be wherever the script is.
I am using:

- CasperJS 1.1.2
- PhantomJS 2.1.1

Running on MacOSX El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G1108)